# Помогите понять выражение

Tags: c++, c

```
if( (mas[i][j] < mas[i][j-1]) && (mas[i][j] < mas[i][j+1]) && (mas[i][j] < mas[i+1][j]) && (mas[i][j] < mas[i-1][j]))
```

особенно не понятно такое кол-во амперсантов

Comment: Здесь проверяется, что элемент `mas[i][j]` меньше чем элементы вокруг него (не учитывая его окружение по диагоналям (углам))

Comment: `&&` значит "И". Все 4 условия должны выполняться одновременно.

Comment: спасибо, теперь стало понятно